# Load layer styles from PostGIS DB with QGIS 3 with PyQt5

Tags: postgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, style-manager

I'm trying to load styles that are stored in a PostGIS database. We have them organised in sets, for each layer that is in the DB. I added comments in the code.

This code was previously 2 lines. Fetch the style names from the database and apply it to the layer using `layer.loadNamedStyle()`, but that didn't work.

In the mean time I'm using a `styleManager()` with bits and pieces I collected from posts on StackExchange. But it still doesn't work and I'm at a loss to figure out why.

I tried to keep the code snippet limited to the essential part, if you need to see more of the code, please let me know.

```
def reload_layers(self):
    self.iface.mapCanvas().layers()

    geometry_column = "geom"
    self.layer_styles = {}

    # remove the layers that will be reloaded from the Legend
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers():
        for table in self.tablenames:
            if layer.title().lower().startswith(table):
                QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer)
    for table in self.tablenames:
        uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
        uri.setConnection(DB_ADDRESS, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD)
        uri.setDataSource("main", table, geometry_column)
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), table, "postgres")
        if not self.layer_styles:
            self.populate_layer_styles(layer)
        if not layer.isValid():
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Layer failed to load", level=Qgis.Critical)
        else:
            # add the layer to the Layers Pane
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
            layer = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer)
            layer.setExpanded(False)
            layer.visibilityChanged.connect(self.update_layout_widgets)
            layer.geometryChanged.connect(self.update_layout_widgets)
            if layer.name().lower().startswith('mow_segment'):
                QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayer(layer).setItemVisibilityChecked(False)
            layer.triggerRepaint()

def populate_layer_styles(self, layer):
    # listStylesInDatabase gives us the names of the styles available in PostGIS, wonderful
    for style in layer.listStylesInDatabase()[2]:
        # We organised them in sets, the 4th character contains a number
        style_set = style[3]
        if style_set not in self.layer_styles:
            self.layer_styles[style_set] = {}
        # Now for the odd part, for each layer, we have to set up a style manager
        style_manager = layer.styleManager()
        from PyQt5.QtXml import QDomDocument
        # it gets weirder, we have to fetch the definition of the style from the database
        query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare("SELECT styleqml FROM public.layer_styles WHERE stylename='{}'".format(style))
        query.exec_()
        result = []
        time.sleep(0.3)
        while query.next():
            result.append(query.value(0))

        if result:
            styleqml = result[0]
            style_doc = QDomDocument()
            style_doc.setContent(styleqml)
            # and import the definition into the style manager
            # But it seems like addStyleFromLayer adds the currently active style
            # So we import the style definition into the layer
            layer.importNamedStyle(style_doc)
            # Load and activate it
            layer.loadNamedStyle(style)
            # And then add it to the style manager
            style_manager.addStyleFromLayer(style)
            # And keep a reference to the style manager
            self.layer_styles[style_set][style] = style_manager
            # Unfortunately all that doesn't work
    # Update radio buttons on the interface
    for style_set in self.layer_styles:
        if style_set not in self.dockwidget.rb_styles.button:
            self.dockwidget.rb_styles.add_button(str(style_set), self.activate_style_set)

def activate_style_set(self, style_set):
    # print(style_set.text())
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        # only for vector layers
        if layer.type() != 0:
            continue
        # Extract table name using light regex
        table_re = re.compile(r'table="main"."(mow_.+?)"')
        table = table_re.search(layer.source())
        if table:
            table = table.group(1)
        else:
            continue
        # And compare it with layer names used for reloading the layers
        if table in self.tablenames:
            style = 'set' + style_set.text() + '-' + table
            # print(style)
            # print(layer.loadNamedStyle(style))
            # style_manager = layer.styleManager()
            print(style_set.text(), style)
            print(self.layer_styles[style_set.text()])
            style_manager = self.layer_styles[style_set.text()][style]
            # style_manager.addStyleFromLayer(style)
            # print(style_manager.mapLayerStyles())
            # # print(style_manager.layer().name())
            # print(style_manager.currentStyle())
            style_manager.setCurrentStyle(style)
            # print(style_manager.currentStyle())
            # print(layer.id())
            self.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working? Where is your blocker? Did you look the DB-Style-Manager plugin in QGIS? I'm trying to do more or less what you are doing: to load all styles from PostGIS for a given layer. https://github.com/PnGuadeloupe/db-style-manager/blob/master/plugin.py#L301

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to looking at your source code  etrimaille , I managed to figure it out. Now it's both more concise and it works the way I want it to.

Before the Layer Legend never got updated with the newly loaded style set. Now it does.

```
    def populate_layer_styles(self, layer):
    styles = layer.listStylesInDatabase()
    for style_id, style_name in zip(styles[1], styles[2]):
        style_set = style_name[3]
        if not style_set in self.layer_styles:
            self.layer_styles[style_set] = {}
        style_layer = style_name[5:]
        lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(style_layer)[0]
        style_manager = lyr.styleManager()
        style_xml = QgsMapLayerStyle(lyr.getStyleFromDatabase(style_id)[0])
        style_manager.addStyle(style_name, style_xml)
        self.layer_styles[style_set][style_layer] = style_manager

    # Update radio buttons on the interface
    for style_set in self.layer_styles:
        if style_set not in self.dockwidget.rb_styles.button:
            self.dockwidget.rb_styles.add_button(str(style_set), self.activate_style_set)

def activate_style_set(self, style_set):
    # print(style_set.text())
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        # only for vector layers
        if layer.type() != 0:
            continue
        # Extract table name using light regex
        table_re = re.compile(r'table="main"."(mow_.+?)"')
        table = table_re.search(layer.source())
        if table:
            table = table.group(1)
        else:
            continue
        # And compare it with layer names used for reloading the layers
        if table in self.tablenames:
            style = 'set' + style_set.text() + '-' + table
            style_manager = self.layer_styles[style_set.text()][style[5:]]
            style_manager.setCurrentStyle(style)
            self.iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refreshAllLayers()
```